Late 90s / Early 2000s movie about girl getting in an accident then learning to run again?
I'm hoping to get some help identifying a movie, for which I don't remember a lot of the premise / plot.
What I do know is that it's about a girl who gets in an accident and becomes physically / mentally disabled. Before the accident she was a runner, and so what I know of the movie is that she is trying to run again with the help of her mother and father.
I also think that at one point she falls and breaks her nose while trying to run before she is ready. And at another point her mother is feeding her / helping her recover.
For a long time I thought the movie starred Leelee Sobieski, but after searching through all of her movies this turned out to not be true - so the lead actress is a L. Sobieski-esk actor.

For the record, there was a Leelee Sobieski movie called 'Here on Earth' where she plays a teenager whom ends up having some sort of cancer in her knee that was from her being in a track accident. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0195778/?ref_=nv_sr_1

@followthemeow Yes, I did find this movie and watched it all the way through, but it turned out not to be what I was looking for.

Could it possibly be this one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqJEA_GILAg

Celle qui reste (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0442032/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), a French Movie TV has the same plot (I just came across looking for the TV Guide). It's not the correct answer, but if someone is looking for it.

Could be The Miracle of Kathy Miller 
From Wikipedia :

The Miracle of Kathy Miller is a 1981 television film based on the real-life story of a  teenager who was critically injured in a car accident. Kathy, a high school track and field athlete, overcame the severe mental and physical injury to compete in and finish a long-distance race.





Omg thank you so much! This is definitely it! I have been looking for this movie for such a long time. Thank you!

glad I could help!
